# AppMgrIII doesn't uninstall android bloatware - only disable

Tags: bloatware

I have an old LGLS660 with 4 MB internal memory making install of new apps almost impossible - added MicroSD card to expand by 16 GB - rooted successfully with kingoroot.

So I d/l this app I was able to move some apps but not uninstall the android ones I don't use which was the entire point of all this fiddling.

How should I get rid of the unwanted apps?

Answer (score 0):

after looking at KINGOROOT more carefully I realized it has built in tools to remove the android apps. So I uninstalled this program b/c it was not necessary.